# Split String into groups

Tags: python, regex, string, string-algorithm

I've a string like this `Delete File/Folder`. I need to break the sentence based on the `/` equivalent to `or`.

Finally need to generate two strings out of this like `Delete File` as one string and `Delete Folder` as the other one.

I've tried very naive way where I check for the index of `/` and then form strings with a bunch of conditions.

It some times fails when we have string like `File/Folder Deleted`.

---

**Edit:**

If you split on `/` then for case 1 we have `Delete File` and `Folder`. Then I'll check for spaces present in first string and spaces present is second string.

The one which has less number of spaces will be replaced with first string last element. This is getting complicated.

Comment: So your code? And why do you mean about *It some times fails when we have string like "File/Folder Deleted"?* **How does it fail?**  PS: Not the downvoter.

Comment: try `"Delete File/Folder".split("/")`

Comment: @Borja: I think OP has tried that.

Comment: Could we please see your regex?

Comment: @Borja: Just I think, and this maybe doesn't work here because OP also need `Delete`(So maybe something like `re.findall(r'\w* .+?/.+? \w*', s)`)

Comment: @Borja: And I'm waiting for OP's reply, I don't know what's OP real asking.

Comment: `Finally need to generate two strings out of this like Delete File as one string and Delete Folder as the other one.`- I don't understand, what is unclear here

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I also don't know why does OP say that his code fails when we have string like  `File/Folder Deleted`. If he's use `.split()` then it doesn't matter. Do you understand it?

Comment: @KevinGuan if you split on / then for case 1 we have Delete File and Folder. Then i'll check for spaces present in first string and spaces present is second string. The one which has less number of spaces will be replaced with first string last element. This is getting complicated.

Comment: Could you please use [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33434086/edit) and add the code that you have to question? Then we can debug for you. And what's the expect output about your second string?

Comment: @KevinGuan the second string should produce "File Deleted" and "Folder Deleted"

Comment: Congratulations! Your question is clear now :). But what about `Delete File/Folder Deleted`?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `Delete File/Folder`, thinking through why the word `Delete` gets distributed to both of `File` and `Folder` might help with the inherent assumptions we all intuitively make when lexical parsing.

For instance, it would be parsed between the the `i` and `l` to return `["Delete File", "Delete FiFolder"]`.

It sounds like you want to want to split the string into words based on where there are spaces and then split each word based on `/` to generate new full strings.

```
>>> import itertools

>>> my_str = "Delete File/Folder"
>>> my_str = ' '.join(my_str.split()).replace('/ ', '/').replace(' /', '/')  # First clean string to ensure there aren't spaces around `/`
>>> word_groups = [word.split('/') for word in my_str.split(' ')]
>>> print [' '.join(words) for words in itertools.product(*word_groups)]
['Delete File', 'Delete Folder']
```

Comment: this one fails when the string is str="Delete File / Folder"

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make above.  The problem itself is ambiguous.  What behavior would you expect for `Delete File/Folder is Deleted`, `Delete File/Folder/Directory`, `Delete File / Delete Folder / Delete Folders`, `Delete File,/Folder`?  You could try getting rid of spaces around `/` first -- I edited my answer to do that.

Comment: thanks a lot! I can modify your solution to fit my requirements.

Comment: this line of code in the begin will complete you solution:my_str = re.sub(r'\s+\/\s+', r'/', my_str)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that? Comment if you want a more generalized solution.

```
lst = your_string.split()[1].split("/")

finalList=[]
for i in lst:
    finalList.append("Delete {0}",i)

print finalList
```

For string:

```
Delete File/Folder
```

Output:

```
['Delete File', 'Delete Folder']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st1 = "Do you want to Delete File/Folder"
st2 = "File/Folder Updated" 

def spl(st):
    import re
    li = []
    ff = re.search(r'\w+/\w+',st).group()
    if ff:
        t = ff.split('/')
        l = re.split(ff,st)
        for el in t:
            if not l[0]:
                li.append((el + ''.join(l)))
            else:
                li.append((''.join(l) + el))
    return li

    for item in st1,st2:
        print(spl(item))

    ['Do you want to Delete File', 'Do you want to Delete Folder']
    ['File Updated', 'Folder Updated']
```

Comment: What about `st = "Do you want to Delete File/Folder?"`?

Comment: yes the whole sentence should be retained provided in each splits along with File or Folder

Comment: @Linus_30 ok now it does the whole sentence

Comment: @LetzerWille but it's not generic, it'll not fit for something like this "File/Folder Updated".

Comment: @Linus_30 assuming that File,Folder are constants with re.split it is made generic. Take a look

Comment: @Linus_30 more general now: it just needs to find a / between any two words

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Do you want to Delete File/Folder?"

word = str.split(" ")

count = str.count("/")

c = True

for j in range(0,2*count):
    for i in word:
        if("/" in i):
            words = i.split("/")

            if c:
                print words[1],

            else:
                print words[0],

        else:
            print i, # comma not to separate line 
    c = not c
    print
```

**output**

```
Do you want to Delete File
Do you want to Delete Folder?
```